# JOLT transform table like JSON to well-formed JSON

Tags: json, jolt

I'm new to jolt, how would I go about transforming this table like json, ignoring the `Header` `RowType`, into more well-formed json.

Input:

```json
{
  "Rows": [
    {
      "RowType": "Header",
      "Cells": [
        {
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Value": "1 Aug 23"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "RowType": "Section",
      "Title": "Income",
      "Rows": [
        {
          "RowType": "Row",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Sales"
            },
            {
              "Value": "18494.43"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "RowType": "SummaryRow",
          "Cells": [
            {
              "Value": "Total Income"
            },
            {
              "Value": "18494.43"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```json
{
  "Income": {
    "Sales": "18494.43",
    "TotalIncome": "18494.43"
  }
}
```

In the original json, there are more `Sections`, but they follow the same sub-structure.

I've tried various options, but I don't seem to be able to pull the value from the Cells[0] as the key for the value of Cells[1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deep down upto innermost in order to reach the level of the *Values* those need to be extracted while seperating their respective objects by `RowType`(`@(3,RowType).`), and attributes by their indexes of the appearance order within the innermost `Cells` arrays(`&&1`->`Value0 and 1`) in the first **shift** transformation spec.

Then match the returned values within the second spec such that

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "*": "@(3,RowType).&&1"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*ow": { //only RowTypes ending with "ow" provided that there might others at the same level
        "@Value1": "@Value0"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the spec and the explanation Barbaros!

Comment: Nice to help, have a good day @Clive !